# Skip last x elements in Stream<T>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have a `Stream<T>`, I can easily use `skip(long)` to skip the first few elements of a stream. However, there seems to be no equivalent for skipping a given number of elements at the end of the stream.

The most obvious solution is to use `limit(originalLength - elementsToRemoveAtEnd)`, but that requires knowing the initial length beforehand, which isn't always the case.

Is there a way to remove the last few elements of a stream of unknown length without having to collect it into a `Collection`, count the elements and stream it again?

Comment: The reason there is no such method is probably the one you are giving. There is normally no way to know when a `Stream` will end during streaming, so you can't really remove the last few elements until you are done.

Comment: How do you determine the point when you want to skip the remaining elements? Couldnt you implement your own Stream to wrap around the original Stream?

Comment: How do you know an element is last if you don't know the length of the stream?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no general storage-free solution for `Stream`s that may have an unknown length. However, you don’t need to collect the entire stream, you only need a storage as large as the number of elements you want to skip:

```
static <T> Stream<T> skipLastElements(Stream<T> s, int count) {
    if(count<=0) {
      if(count==0) return s;
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(count+" < 0");
    }
    ArrayDeque<T> pending=new ArrayDeque<T>(count+1);
    Spliterator<T> src=s.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterator<T>() {
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            while(pending.size()<=count && src.tryAdvance(pending::add));
            if(pending.size()>count) {
              action.accept(pending.remove());
              return true;
            }
          return false;
        }
        public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
            return null;
        }
        public long estimateSize() {
            return src.estimateSize()-count;
        }
        public int characteristics() {
            return src.characteristics();
        }
    }, false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    skipLastElements(Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world"), 2)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: The above has a serious hidden problem!  Calling `Stream.spliterator()` can return a `StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator`.  The method `initPartialTraversalState()` stores all of the stream elements into a `Collection` (i.e. `SpinedBuffer`)!  This could blow up the heap for streams based on file inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses `ArrayDeque` to buffer `n` elements where `n` is the number of elements to skip at the end.  The trick is to use `skip(n)`.  This causes the first `n` elements to be added to the `ArrayDeque`.  Then, once `n` elements have been buffered, the stream continues processing elements but pops elements from `ArrayDeque`.  When the end of the stream is reached, the last `n` elements are stuck in the `ArrayDeque` and discarded.

`ArrayDeque` does not allow `null` elements.  The code below maps `null` into `NULL_VALUE` before adding to `ArrayDeque` and then maps `NULL_VALUE` back to `null` after popping from `ArrayDeque`.

```
private static final Object NULL_VALUE = new Object();

public static <T> Stream<T> skipLast(Stream<T> input, int n)                   
{
   ArrayDeque<T> queue;

   if (n <= 0)
      return(input);

   queue = new ArrayDeque<>(n + 1);

   input = input.
      map(item -> item != null ? item : NULL_VALUE).
      peek(queue::add).
      skip(n).
      map(item -> queue.pop()).
      map(item -> item != NULL_VALUE ? item : null);

   return(input);
}
```

Comment: Well, I prefer a solution that might be inefficient, depending on how Streams are implemented, over a solution that might break, depending on how Streams are implemented. Your solution relies on the current implementation’s inability to fuse a `skip` with the stream source. A future version might be able to truly skip all preceding steps that do not change the stream size, just like Java 9’s `count()` may not evaluate these functions…

Comment: I have heard those rumors but those optimizations will have to be limited in scope of application or a lot of code will end up broken.  `peek()` should stop such optimizations because its lambda is almost always going to have side-effects.  Thus, `skip()` and `count()` cannot optimize it away.

Comment: Java 9’s `count()` *does* already break such code. As already discussed in [In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488), you should not use a method contrary to its purpose. Since this method’s primary purpose is to debug, i.e. detect *whether* elements are processed at this stage, it would be nonsensical to force processing at this stage *because* of this method. You can not only use the method to detect the presence of such optimization, you may detect that streams sometimes process more elements than necessary, under Java 8 *and* Java 9.