# multiple lines of code in stream.forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code for reading lines of a file:

```
String fileName = "dataset/ANC-all-count.txt";
Integer i=0;
//read file into stream, try-with-resources
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {

    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    i++;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("count is : "+i);
```

but the problem is I need to put `i++` inside the following line:

```
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

So I want something like this:

```
stream.forEach(System.out::println; i++);
```

But it does not work this way so can anyone help how I can make it work?

Comment: create your own lambda doing what you want.

Comment: @vaxquis a lambda expression may not assign a new value to i.

Comment: @JBNizet in general, lamdba *may* assign new value to `i` - it just can't do that directly, if `i` is not effectively final. if he had declared it as a field, there shouldn't be any real problem with it. he asked "[how to have] multiple lines of code in stream.forEach" - the answer is "create a lamdba instead of using method reference"; while in this particular case your answer is excellent, it wouldn't help him in a more general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `peek()` and `count()`:

```
i = (int) stream.peek(System.out::println) 
                .count();
```

Comment: +1 but note that in the future, `count()` will be optimized to directly return the size if the spliterator reports the SIZED characteristic. Thus the `peek` operation may not be performed. This is probably not the case when you get a stream from a file but some using this code should be aware of that.

Comment: I would not recommend using `peek()`, according to JavaDoc `peek`exists mainly to support debugging
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: The problems with `peek` have been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636377/2711488)…

Comment: @AlexisC. that would drastically change the behavior of the method, which is explicitely documented as doing the equivalent of a reduce(). Is that really something that will happen?

Comment: @AlexisC. BTW, would this optimization still be done if the stream has an intermediate operation (like peek()) before the count? I'd be OK with the optimization if it was done when there is no intermediate op, but would find it an unwise choice if there is one.

Comment: @JBNizet See the api note: http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--

Comment: @AlexisC. Good to know thanks. One more pain point when migrating to Java 9. They should put that warning NOW in the Java 8 javadoc.

Answer (score 8):

There are two completely different things you should ask here:

`a)` how do I place multiple lines of code in `stream.forEach()`?

`b)` what should I do to count the number of lines in a `Stream`?

The question `b)` is answered already by other posters; on the other hand, the general question `a)` has a quite different answer:

*use a (possibly multi-line) lambda expression **or** pass a reference to multi-line method*.

In this particular case, you'd either declare `i` a field or use a counter/wrapper object instead of `i`.

For example, if you want to have multiple lines in `forEach()` *explicitly*, you can use

```
class Counter { // wrapper class
    private int count;
    public int getCount() { return count; }
    public void increaseCount() { count++; }
}
```

and then

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
lines.stream().forEach( e -> {
    System.out.println(e);
    counter.increaseCounter(); // or i++; if you decided i is worth being a field
} );
```

Another way to do it, this time hiding those multiple lines in a method:

```
class Counter { // wrapper class
    private int count;
    public int getCount() { return count; }
    public void increaseCount( Object o ) {
        System.out.println(o);
        count++;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
lines.stream().forEach( counter::increaseCount );
```

or even

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
lines.stream().forEach( e -> counter.increaseCount(e) );
```

The second syntax comes in handy if you need a consumer having more than one parameter; the first syntax is still the shortest and simplest though.

Answer (score 6):

The `forEach` method takes an instance of any class that implements `Consumer`. So here is an example of using a custom `Consumer` implementation that keeps up with the count. Later you can call `getCount()` on the `Consumer` implementation to get the count.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ConsumerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("line 1");
        lines.add("line 2");

        MyConsumer countingConsumer = new MyConsumer();
        lines.stream().forEach(countingConsumer);
        System.out.println("Count: " + countingConsumer.getCount());
    }

    private static class MyConsumer implements Consumer<String> {
        private int count;

        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            System.out.println(t);
            count++;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I'm a lambda novice to be honest, but I've been doing Java for 10 years so I figured I would give a solution with what I know.

Comment: @vaxquis I didn't mention lambdas in my answer and the question didn't require an answer use lambdas. So I'm not sure why you want me to add it to my answer.

Comment: @vaxquis I actually created the class with the intention of using lambdas but didn't end up doing it. I just needed a class with a main. It could be called XYZ for all I care. My main goal was to inform about the Consumer interface. Good change though, it could be misleading otherwise to future viewers.