# Intermediate steps in the pipeline

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Very new to stream API's so pardon me if this is a basic question. I am trying to convert this code snippet to use Java 8 stream

```
    Resultset results = new Resultset();
    List<Object[]> terms = service.search(term);
    Map<Long, TermResult> resultMap = new HashMap<Long, TermResult>();
    for(Object[] term : terms) {
        Long id = (Long)term[0];
        String termStr = (String)term[1];
        TermResult termResult = new TermResult(id, termStr);
        resultMap.put(id, termResult);
        results.addResult(termResult);
    }
```

`terms` is a list of object array with id in `Object[0]` and term in `Object[1]`.The above code basically does the following -

1. Convert the `terms` list to `resultMap` with the key `id` and value `TermResult` object
2. Add the `TermResult` into a `results` set

I was able to convert #1 to use stream -

```
 Map<Long, TermResult> resultMap =
                    terms.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> (Long)p[0], p -> new TermResult((Long)p[0], (String)p[1])));
```

But how would I sneak in #2 in the above pipeline?

This is what I came up with using `peek` -

```
Map<Long, TermResult> resultMap =
                terms.stream().map(p -> new TermResult((Long)p[0], (String)p[1]))
                        .peek(p -> results.addResult(p))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getId(), p -> p));
```

1. Is this the right way to do this?
2. Also can this be done in parallel? I want `results` to be in same order as `terms` list(sorted by term). I tried using `parallelStream` in the above code snippet. But the order is not preserved in `results`.

Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: See also [“In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488)

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't be done in parallel; certainly not if `results` is not thread-safe and even then not while preserving order.  (And additionally -- adding parallelism before you've actually measured how long an operation takes is *almost always* a bad idea.  Parallelism is more likely to hurt performance than help if you just slap it everywhere.)

All this said, streams are really not intended to do more than one thing at once.  You'd almost certainly be better off *just* creating the map and then iterating through its `values()`, or just creating a `Set` out of them depending on what `results` actually is.  You *could* do it the way you described, but you *shouldn't.*