# For loop including if to parallelStream() expression

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-stream

Is there a way to parallelize this piece of code:

```
HashMap<String, Car> cars;
List<Car> snapshotCars = new ArrayList<>();
...
for (final Car car : cars.values()) {
    if (car.isTimeInTimeline(curTime)) {
        car.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime);
        snapshotCars.add(car);
    }
}
```

Update: This is what I tried before asking for assistance:

```
snapshotCars.addAll(cars.values().parallelStream()
                                 .filter(c -> c.isTimeInTimeline(curTime))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

How could I integrate this line? ->
car.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime);

Comment: Have you tried converting to the stream API? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Sure is. Now you should try. Don't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I want you to tell me how to write it. Small semantic difference I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that `updateCalculatedPosition` does not affect state outside of the `Car` object on which it runs, it may be safe enough to use `peek` for this:

```
List<Car> snapshotCars = cars.values()
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(c -> c.isTimeInTimeline(curTime))
    .peek(c -> c.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

I say this is "safe enough" because the `collect` dictates which elements will be peeked by `peek`, and these will necessarily be all the items that passed the filter. However, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636377/4125191) for the reason why `peek` should generally be avoided for "significant" operations.

Your peek-free alternative is to first, filter and collect, and then update using the finished collection:

```
List<Car> snapshotCars = cars.values()
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(c -> c.isTimeInTimeline(curTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
snapShotCars.parallelStream()
    .forEach(c -> c.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime));
```

This is safer from an API point of view, but less parallel - you only start updating the positions after you have finished filtering and collecting.

Comment: Unless the OP says explicitly that an `ArrayList` is needed, I would simply use `Collectors.toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want parallelized access to a List you might want to use `Collections.synchonizedList` to get a thread-safe list:

```
List<Car> snapshotCars = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Then you can use the stream API like so:

```
cars.values()
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(car -> car.isTimeInTimeline(curTime))
    .forEach(car -> {
        car.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime);
        snapshotCars.add(car);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [RealSkeptic’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659498/2711488), you can alternatively use your own collector:

```
List<Car> snapshotCars = cars.values().parallelStream()
    .filter(c -> c.isTimeInTimeline(curTime))
    .collect(ArrayList::new,
             (l,c) -> { c.updateCalculatedPosition(curTime); l.add(c); },
             List::addAll);
```

Note that `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is equivalent (though not necessarily identical) to `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` which is equivalent to `.collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll)`.

So our custom collector does a similar operation, but replaces the accumulator with a function, which also performs the desired additional operation.