# How to specify Predicate in Java Stream when found too many items

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for some object in map:

```
mapObjects.entrySet().stream().map(map -> map.getValue()).filter(predicateA)
```

When I find more then one item, I want to specify a second predicate to filter on some additional attribute. Is there some way I can do this in just one iteration of stream, or do I need to iterate once and when `count > 1` then I need to iterate a second time with another predicate ?

For example, say I have list of persons. First I am looking for `name=John`. When there is more than one John, I look for `surname=Smith`. Now I don't care if there is more than one and I just take the first.

Comment: You can use a stateful `Predicate` - but note that that won't work with a parallel `Stream`.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. You should index your data by your predicate, and then detect duplicates. This will be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: You can replace `mapObjects.entrySet().stream().map(map -> map.getValue())` with `mapObjects.values().stream()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider A stateful predicate would work, the state just needs to be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by first filtering the `Person` instances by `name` then grouping by `surname`. The result will be put into a `LinkedHashMap` in order to get the first match if there is no full match (`name` and `surname`), finally we rely on `Map#getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` to get the full match if it exists otherwise it will get the first entry as default value.

```
Map<String, Person> map = mapObjects.values().stream()
    .filter(p -> Objects.equals(p.getName(), name))
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getSurname, 
            LinkedHashMap::new, 
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> list.get(0))
        )
    );

Optional<Person> result =
    map.isEmpty() ?
        Optional.absent() :
        Optional.of(
            map.getOrDefault(surname, map.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue())
        );
```

This way you iterate only once to get your result and you don't use a stateful `Predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reduction operation which prioritizes the second predicate when possible:

```
mapObjects.values().stream()
    .filter(predicateA)
    .reduce((acc, obj) -> predicateB.test(obj) ? obj : acc)
    .ifPresent(doThing);
```

Unfortunately, the reduction can't be short-circuited. If this is important, keep reading.

---

You could give `predicateB` a wrapping class which only tries to return true if it never has before and the argument meets the criteria. Here is an atomic implementation so that it still works in parallel streams.

```
public class ShortCircuitPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    private final AtomicBoolean hasBeenTrue;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;
    private ShortCircuitPredicate(Predicate<T> pred) {
        hasBeenTrue = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        predicate = pred;
    }

    public static <T> ShortCircuitPredicate<T> of(Predicate<T> pred) {
        return new ShortCircuitPredicate<>(pred);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        return hasBeenTrue.get()
            ? false
            : predicate.test(t) && hasBeenTrue.compareAndSet(false, true);
    }
}
```

You can wrap `predicateB` using `ShortCircuitPredicate.of(predicateB)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced this problem is a good fit for using the stream API, but an option would be to rely on [Stream#peek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) to keep a reference to one of the elements that matches the first filter, if none match the second one:

```
    List<Person> people = ...
    Person[] holder = new Person[1];

    Person result = people.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("John"))
            .peek(p -> holder[0] = p)
            .filter(p -> p.getSurname().equals("Smith"))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(holder[0]);
```

This is short-circuiting in case there is any match for both filters. On the other hand, `peek()` and the second filter will have to be executed on all matches of the first predicate before `findAny()` returns an empty optional. Consequently, the holder will always be filled, except when there is no match to the first predicate.

I suggested carefully reading [In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging) though, and make your own opinion on whether this is an appropriate option for your specific case.