# Java Streams — How to perform an intermediate function every nth item

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for an operation on a Stream that enables me to perform a non-terminal (and/or terminal) operation every nth item. Although I use a stream of primes for example, the stream could just as easily be web-requests, user actions, or some other cold data or live feed being produced.

From this:

```
    Duration start = Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime());

    IntStream.iterate(2, n -> n + 1)
            .filter(Findprimes::isPrime)
            .limit(1_000_1000 * 10)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("Duration: " + Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime()).minus(start));
```

To a stream function like this:

```
    IntStream.iterate(2, n -> n + 1)
            .filter(Findprimes::isPrime)
            .limit(1_000_1000 * 10)
            .peekEvery(10, System.out::println)
            .forEach( it -> {});
```

Comment: This sort of operation is really best done *without streams.*. Streams just aren't suited to this sort of operations.  Don't try to force it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a helper method to wrap the `peek()` consumer:

```
public static IntConsumer every(int count, IntConsumer consumer) {
    if (count <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Count must be >1: Got " + count);
    return new IntConsumer() {
        private int i;
        @Override
        public void accept(int value) {
            if (++this.i == count) {
                consumer.accept(value);
                this.i = 0;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

You can now use it almost exactly like you wanted:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
         .peek(every(5, System.out::println))
         .count();
```

*Output*

```
5
10
15
20
```

The helper method can be put in a utility class and statically imported, similar to how the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class is nothing but static helper methods.

As noted by @user140547 in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055391/java-streams-how-to-perform-an-intermediate-function-every-nth-item/40055708#comment67389331_40055708), this code is not thread-safe, so it cannot be used with parallel streams. Besides, the output order would be messed up, so it doesn't really make sense to use it with parallel streams anyway.

Comment: I'm going to go with this. Although @saka1029 has a more local and readable algorithm, yours is make-once, use-everywhere, and it could fit nicely into any Streamhelper library. Nice!

Comment: If you use a parallel stream, you might end up with an output like `15
20 10 5`. Also, this implementation is not thread-safe and should be synchronized when using a parallel stream, so you may get any result.

Comment: @user140547: to be correct, if you use this with a parallel Stream, there are tons of different possible outputs, showing *arbitrary* numbers rather than the desired numbers in different order, and even making the method `synchronized` won’t fix that. This a consumer that relies on the *processing* order, while the desired result depends on the *encounter* order. Further, `peek` is meant to help debugging the processing only, not to perform a required action, i.e. under Java 9, this code will do nothing, because the `count` of a `rangeClosed` can be calculated without processing any items…

Comment: See [In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636377/2711488); this solution exactly falls into the two of the traps mentioned there…

Comment: @Holger: well true, synchronizing won't help here. peek is probably seldom a good idea. Anyway, if forEach returned a `long` representing the number of elements processed, there would be fewer attempts to use `peek().count()` ...

Comment: @user140547: but in this specific case, the OP isn’t actually interested in the total count. Using `forEach` would still be a victim of unspecified processing order, using `forEachOrdered` using a statefull `Consumer` can solve the entire problem, of course, at the expense of destroying almost any benefit of parallel processing when being used with a parallel stream.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good idea to rely on `peek()` and `count()` as **it is possible that the operation is not invoked at all** if `count()` can be calculated without going over the whole stream. Even if it works now, it does not mean that it is also going to work in future. See the [javadoc of `Stream.count()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) in Java 9.

Better use `forEach()`.

For the problem itself: In special cases like a simple iteration, you could just filter your objects like.

```
Stream.iterate(2, n->n+1)
        .limit(20)
        .filter(n->(n-2)%5==0 && n!=2)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This of course won't work for other cases, where you might use a stateful `IntConsumer`. If `iterate()` is used, it is probably not that useful to use parallel streams anyway.

If you want a generic solution, you could also try to use a "normal" `Stream`, which may not be as efficient as an `IntStream`, but should still suffice in many cases:

```
class Tuple{ // ctor, getter/setter omitted
    int index;
    int value;
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Stream.iterate( new Tuple(1,2),t-> new Tuple(t.index+1,t.value*2))
        .limit(30)
        .filter(t->t.index %5 == 0)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you have to use `peek()`, you can also do

`.peek(t->{if (t.index %5 == 0) System.out.println(t);})`

Or if you add methods

```
static Tuple initialTuple(int value){
   return new Tuple(1,value);
}

static UnaryOperator<Tuple> createNextTuple(IntUnaryOperator f){
    return current -> new Tuple(current.index+1,f.applyAsInt(current.value));
}
static Consumer<Tuple> every(int n,IntConsumer consumer){
    return tuple -> {if (tuple.index % n == 0) consumer.accept(tuple.value);};
}
```

you can also do (with static imports):

```
  Stream.iterate( initialTuple(2), createNextTuple(x->x*2))
        .limit(30)
        .peek(every(5,System.out::println))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: holy crabs. Was not aware of that. Thanks for the heads-up. Editing ...

Comment: @SaintHill: added another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int[] counter = {0};
long result = IntStream.iterate(2, n -> n + 1)
    .filter(Findprimes::isPrime)
    .limit(100)
    .peek(x -> { if (counter[0]++ % 10 == 0) System.out.print(x + " ");} )
    .count();
```

result:

```
2 31 73 127 179 233 283 353 419 467
```

Comment: Was wondering if there was some way to do it without an external counter variable. But that would work! Any stream libraries you know that have such a feature?

Comment: Nice use of counter[0] to avoid an AtomicInteger or other IntRef class :)