# Java 8 stream getting cannot invoke map on primitive type void

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am playing around with streams and lambdas in Java 8, as I have never used them before and was trying to convert the ages of everyone who is 20 to 19 and the printing out their names, but I get the following error

```
Cannot invoke map(Person::getName) on the primitive type void
```

Here is my code

```
            System.out.println(
                people.stream()
                .filter(person -> person.getAge() == 20)
                .forEach(person -> person.setAge(19))
                .map(Person::getName));
```

If someone could tell me why this is happening or let me know how to improve or amend this code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s the purpose of a trailing `.map` operation?

Comment: @Holger I wanted to print out the names of the people who's age had changed

Comment: Then, `.forEach(person -> { person.setAge(19); System.out.println(person.getName()); });` is straight-forward…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a terminal operation and will not return the stream it works on.

In general, you should avoid using `forEach` to modify the stream, even as a final operation. Instead, you should use `map` to modify the items of your stream.

Here is an example of how to do it, which includes a legitimate use of `forEach` :

```
people.stream()
      .filter(person -> person.getAge() == 20)
      .map(person -> new Person(person.getName(), person.getAge() -1 /*, ...*/))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

A few notes on that code :

- `map(...)` only transforms the stream, not the datasource (the `people` `Collection`). If you want to use the transformed result later, you will want to `.collect()` the `Stream` into a new `Collection` with an appropriate `Collector` (e.g. `Collectors.toList()`)
- if you follow that road, your new terminal operation is `collect()`, and you can't use `.forEach()` anymore. One solution would be to use the `.forEach()` method of the new `Collection` (no need for a `stream`, `forEach()` is implemented on `Iterable` since 1.8), another would be to use `.peek()` on the stream where you `map()` as a non-terminal equivalent to `.forEach()`
- About the use of `peek()`, note that the non-terminal operations are driven by the terminal operation : if this one only returns a single element of the stream (like `.findFirst()`), non-terminal operations will only be executed for this element, and you shouldn't expect otherwise.

Comment: Can you also add something about how this code can be made to work or why it isn't a good idea to do this at all?

Comment: You're right for forEach. map isn't the solution though, because person.setAge(19) probably returns void.

Comment: Please don't recreate every Person just to setAge.

Comment: I'm divided here. On one hand I agree recreating a new object just to change one of its properties is wasteful. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure `peek` isn't intended to modify a stream.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for you answer it worked, but instead of creating a new person in map i just did person -> person.getName and it worked perfectly

Comment: It doesn't necessarily modify a stream. It's just here to perform an action (could be println(), could be setAge()) while returning the original stream.

Comment: @user6248190 : but then, how do you setAge(19) ?

Comment: @user6248190 that's not the same thing : instead of mapping your original `Person` stream to a stream of `Person` aged one less year, you mapped your stream to a stream of `String` which are the names of the `Person` with still the same age

Comment: @EricDuminil when it doesn't modify the stream I'm all for `peek` as an intermediate operation equivalent to `forEach`. However, I believe neither `forEach` nor `peek` should modify the stream as a good practice. I'm not sure where this belief comes from, so maybe it's not justified.

Comment: @Aaron oh right I get you, using your solution actually changes the ages of the people where as my one just prints out people who are 20

Comment: I believe peek should not be interfering : that is, modifying the elements is fine, but modifying the stream itself isn't.

Comment: @EricDuminil You're right that peek and forEach should be non-interfering, but I'm not sure about your interpretation of what it means. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) says "For most data sources, preventing interference means ensuring that the data source is not modified at all during the execution of the stream pipeline."

Comment: "data source" : for example a file, but not the lines inside it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your feedback! I'm still not totally convinced, but I'll make sure to further research this point.

Comment: Okay. I think I found what the biggest problem with peek is : it is only called if some terminal operation comes after it. Without forEach after, it won't get called. I updated my answer with a forEach example, without having to create a new Person.

Comment: As long as you can prove that the same `Person` instance will never be twice in the stream, calling `setAge` in one action has no interference (otherwise, you’re modifying the same property that the `filter` accesses). Still, you should consider [“… is peek really only for debugging?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488)

Comment: Thanks @Holger. The accepted answer merely supports my opinion, but the most upvoted one really is enlightening!

Comment: Excellent point Holger. I stand corrected. Peek might be sometimes more elegant, but what good is it if it doesn't always work? I'll update my answer with only forEach

Comment: map has the same problem as peek here : its execution depends on what comes after. Without forEach after, it won't get called. And I still think it's wrong to create a new Person. It might be fine in this example, but this pattern could lead to big problems/bugs with other classes.

Comment: @EricDuminil I agree, I have to revise my answer. I don't have the time right now but I should be able un a few hours, I'll notify you once it's done

Comment: @Aaron: a few months later ... :)

Comment: @EricDuminil hey, thanks for reminding me ! I've had some difficulty finding how to integrate the result of our interesting conversation in the answer without going off-topic, please tell me if you think anything can be added !

Answer (score 3):

You can write multiple statements inside of forEach :

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "(" + age + ")";
    }
}

public class LambdaPeople
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person andy = new Person("Andy", 19);
        Person bob = new Person("Bob", 21);
        Person caroline = new Person("Caroline", 20);

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(caroline);
        people.add(andy);
        people.add(bob);

        people.stream()
                .filter(person -> person.getAge() == 20)
                .forEach(person -> {
                    person.setAge(19);
                    System.out.println(person);
                });
    }
}
```

It returns :

```
Caroline(19)
```

The two next methods are for documentation purpose. peek and map are  intermediate operations. Without forEach at the end, they wouldn't be executed at all.

If you want to use map :

```
    people.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getAge() == 20)
            .map(person -> {
                person.setAge(19);
                return person;
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to use peek :

```
    people.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getAge() == 20)
            .peek(person -> person.setAge(19))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```