# Java - Basic streams usage of forEach

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class called `Data` which has only one method:

```
public boolean isValid()
```

I have a `List`of `Data`and I want to loop through them via a Java 8 stream. I need to count how many `valid` `Data` objects there are in this `List` and print out only the `valid` entries.

Below is how far I've gotten but I don't understand how.

```
List<Data> ar = new ArrayList<>();
...
// ar is now full of Data objects.
...

int count = ar.stream()
            .filter(Data::isValid)
            .forEach(System.out::println)
            .count(); // Compiler error, forEach() does not return type stream.
```

My second attempt: (horrible code)

```
List<Data> ar = new ArrayList<>();
...
// Must be final or compiler error will happen via inner class.
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
ar.stream()
    .filter(Data:isValid)
    .forEach(d -> 
    {
        System.out.println(d);
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    };
System.out.printf("There are %d/%d valid Data objects.%n", counter.get(), ar.size());
```

Comment: Either `peek` or `collect` to a `List`, get its `size` and print it out.

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t need the original `ArrayList`, containing a mixture of valid and invalid objects, later-on, you might simply perform a Collection operation instead of the Stream operation:

```
ar.removeIf(d -> !d.isValid());
ar.forEach(System.out::println);
int count = ar.size();
```

Otherwise, you can implement it like

```
List<Data> valid = ar.stream().filter(Data::isValid).collect(Collectors.toList());
valid.forEach(System.out::println);
int count = valid.size();
```

Having a storage for something you need multiple times is not so bad. If the list is really large, you can reduce the storage memory by (typically) factor 32, using

```
BitSet valid = IntStream.range(0, ar.size())
    .filter(index -> ar.get(index).isValid())
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
valid.stream().mapToObj(ar::get).forEach(System.out::println);
int count = valid.cardinality();
```

Though, of course, you can also use

```
int count = 0;
for(Data d: ar) {
    if(d.isValid()) {
        System.out.println(d);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: neat solution (as usual from u). one question still. where did the 32 appear here? it's not like we really know the Data internals and how much that class weights.

Comment: @Eugene: the `BitSet` uses exactly one bit per entry, whereas an `ArrayList` stores a reference per entry, which is typically 32 bit (either matching the architecture or due to the use of compressed OOPs). It’s not about the per-object overhead, but how these data structures *scale* with large sizes. Of course, we should be careful with assumptions about internals, but certain implementation classes bear their fundamental nature even in its name (“bit” or “array”) to allow the developer to make an appropriate choice. The factor may be even 64 instead of 32, but that’s why I wrote “typically”…

Comment: so 32 comes from diff between the reference storage and one single bit in BitSet. Would it be appropriate to call this factor the *shallow* difference, as opposed to *deep* difference?

Comment: @Eugene: well, here it is the *only* difference…

Answer (score 4):

Peek is similar to foreach, except that it lets you continue the stream.

```
ar.stream().filter(Data::isValid)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .count();
```

Comment: Why would I ever use `forEach` then?

Comment: @Hatefiend you use foreach when you want to iterate over a list, perform some operations on each of its objects and leave.
Say you want to compute the total interest for a list of customers. You could just use foreach and on each object call `calculateInterest()`.
The result of this is anyways saved on the Original Customer Object, so you don't have to collect it either.

Comment: But by this logic I could just do `list.peek(x -> x.calculateInterest(); };` No? How does that differ from forEach()

Comment: Also I see that `peek` is a suggest debug only method. See the following [api link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: @Hatefiend See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging