# Java 8 FlatMap - Add items in a nested form and retrieve object using FlatMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, flatmap

I have an object `Foo` which contains a list of `Bar`. The classes are described as follows:

```
class Foo {
    String name;
    List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();

    Foo(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Bar {
    String name;

    Bar(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now, i am creating a list of `Foo` objects, each containing a list of `Bar` objects as follows:

```
IntStream
        .range(1, 4)
        .forEach(i -> foos.add(new Foo("Foo" + i)));

foos.forEach(f ->
            IntStream.range(1,4)
                    .forEach(i -> f.bars.add(new Bar("Bar"+i+" -> "+f.name))));
```

And then using `flatMap` on a `Stream` as follows:

```
foos.stream()
        .flatMap(f -> f.bars.stream())
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Bar Name : "+i.name));
```

How can do all these things in a single execution using Java `Stream` and lambdas? Is there any other way to do such kind of things with Java 8 style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you’re going to do, is to print the names of the `Bar` instances, the entire construction and collection of `Foo` and `Bar` instances is obsolete. You can generate and print the names directly:

```
IntStream.range(1, 4)
         .mapToObj(i -> "Foo" + i)
         .flatMap(name -> IntStream.range(1, 4)
            .mapToObj(i -> "Bar" + i + "->" + name))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the `Foo` instances in `mapToObj` instead of `forEach` :

```
IntStream.range(1, 4)
         .mapToObj (i -> {Foo foo = new Foo("Foo" + i);
                          foo.bars =
                              IntStream.range(1,4)
                                       .mapToObj(j -> new Bar("Bar"+j+" -> "+foo.name))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
                          return foo;
                    })
         .flatMap (f -> f.bars.stream())
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Bar Name : "+i.name));
```

This, however, won't store the created `Foo` instances in a `List`. If you want to store them in a `List`, either split the operation to 2 `Stream` pipelines (the first ending in `collect(Collectors.toList())`) or use `peek(f->foos.add(f))` to add the `Foo` instances into the `foos` `List` (which will require that you instantiate the `foos` `List` before running the pipeline).

EDIT:

Fixed some typos and tested the code :

```
Bar Name : Bar1 -> Foo1
Bar Name : Bar2 -> Foo1
Bar Name : Bar3 -> Foo1
Bar Name : Bar1 -> Foo2
Bar Name : Bar2 -> Foo2
Bar Name : Bar3 -> Foo2
Bar Name : Bar1 -> Foo3
Bar Name : Bar2 -> Foo3
Bar Name : Bar3 -> Foo3
```

Comment: I got the following compile error using your answer: The method mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> i) -> 
 {})

Comment: @KaranVerma All is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the resolution from following pipeline operations using peek and mapToObject...

```
IntStream.range(1, 4)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Foo("Foo"+i))
            .peek(f -> IntStream.range(1, 4)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new Bar("Bar"+i+"->"+f.name))
                    .forEach(f.bars::add))
            .flatMap(f -> f.bars.stream())
            .forEach(b -> System.out.println("Bar : "+b.name));
```

Comment: Using `peek` for that is not recommended.

Comment: What is the problem with peek?

Comment: It’s explicitly declared to be a function mainly for debugging. See also [“In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488)

Comment: Got it now @Holger