# Getting filtered records from streams using lambdas in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an entity Employee

```
class Employee{
          private String name;
          private String addr;
          private String sal;
 }
```

Now i have list of these employees. I want to filter out those objects which has name = null and set addr = 'A'. I was able to achieve like below :

```
List<Employee> list2=    list.stream()
            .filter(l ->  l.getName() != null)
            .peek(l -> l.setAddr("A"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now list2 will have all those employees whose name is not null and then set addr as A for those employees.
What i also want to find is those employees which are filtered( name == null) and save them in DB.One way i achieved is like below :

```
List<Employee> list2=    list.stream()
            .filter(l -> filter(l))
            .peek(l -> l.setAddr("A"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

private static boolean filter(Employee l){
    boolean j = l.getName() != null;
    if(!j)
          // save in db
    return j;
}
```

1) Is this the right way?

2) Can we do this directly in lambda expression instead of writing separate method?

Comment: 1) No, side effects in functions are not the right approach and using `peek` for purposes other than debugging is discouraged. 2) Replace everything before the first `{` of the method with `l -> ` and you have a lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you should *not* use side effect in behavioral parameters. See the sections [“Stateless behaviors” and “Side-effects” of the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). Also, it’s not recommended to use `peek` for non-debugging purposes, see [“In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717)

There’s not much advantage in trying to squeeze all these different operations into a single Stream pipeline. Consider the clean alternative:

```
Map<Boolean,List<Employee>> m = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(l -> l.getName() != null));
m.get(false).forEach(l -> {
    // save in db
});
List<Employee> list2 = m.get(true);
list2.forEach(l -> l.setAddr("A"));
```

Regarding your second question, a lambda expression allows almost everything, a method does. The differences are on the declaration, i.e. you can’t declare additional type parameters nor annotate the return type. Still, you should avoid writing too much code into a lambda expression, as, of course, you can’t create test cases directly calling that code. But that’s a matter of programming style, not a technical limitation.

Comment: I did not ever think about this testing limitation, good point indeed. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay in using peek for implementing your logic (though it is not recommended unless for learning), you can do the following:

```
List<Employee> list2=    list.stream()
        .peek(l -> { // add this peek to do persistence
              if(l.getName()==null){
                  persistInDB(l);
              }
        }).filter(l ->  l.getName() != null)
        .peek(l -> l.setAddr("A"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also do something like this:

```
    List<Employee> list2 =    list.stream()
              .filter(l->{
                  boolean condition = l.getName()!=null;
                  if(condition){
                      l.setAddr("A");
                  } else {
                      persistInDB(l);
                  }
                  return condition;
              })
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope this helps!