# Abusing Optional#map considering absent Optional#peek method

Tags: java, java-8

Consider following classes:

```
ClassA {
}

ClassB {
    private ClassA classA;

    // getters and setters
}
```

As there is no `peek` method available on `Optional`, is this considered abusing the `Optional#map` method:

```
return myService.findA()
        .flatMap(a -> myService.findB(a) // also returns optional
                    .map(b -> {
                            b.setClassA(a);
                            return b;
                        }))
        .map(d -> MyType.of(d)) // MyType being other class
        .orElse(MyType.empty());
```

This could also be written like this:

```
Optional<ClassA> optionalA = myService.findA();

if (optionalA.isPresent()) {
    Optional<ClassB> optionalB = myService.findB(optionalA.get());

    if (optionalB.isPresent()) {
        ClassB classB = optionalB.get();
        classB.setClassA(optionalA.get());
        return MyType.of(classB);
}
return MyType.empty();
```

Both implementations perform the same logic, should one be preferred over the other ?

Comment: IMHO, (a) yes, that's abuse, as `map` should probably not have any side effects, and (b) the "old-style" code might be a bot more verbose, but it's much, _much_ clearer and easier to comprehend.

Comment: at the same time java doc for peek says: This method exists mainly to support debugging. So it is an open question what to use for state mutation `peek` or `map`. Please see [peek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging) and [map vs peek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117419/better-way-than-stream-peek)

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc neither. There is already `ifPresent` in the class `Optional` which is explicitly made for performing an action.

Comment: @tobias_k not "probably" but "absolutely". Methods passed to map should be functions, which are pure by definition.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it looks strange that `myService.findB(a)` doesn’t already imply `b.setClassA(a)`, as it has both in scope, but anyway, there is no need to abuse `map` here:

```
return myService.findA()
    .flatMap(a -> {
        Optional<B> oB = myService.findB(a);
        oB.ifPresent(b -> b.setClassA(a));
        return oB;
    })
    .map(MyType::of).orElse(MyType.empty());
```

Comment: This _is_ much clearer than OP's version (both, IMHO), but isn't this still an abuse of `flatMap` just as it was of `map`?

Comment: @tobias_k the problem with the `map` in the original version was that it was added merely for performing an action with side-effect; it didn’t really *map* the value to something else. The `flatMap` of my answer still is used in the intended way, to perform an operation that evaluates to another `Optional`. If you’re still not convinced, you can encapsulate `myService.findB(a);` and `oB.ifPresent(b -> b.setClassA(a));` into a new method on its own and call this method in `flatMap`; as said, I’d expect `findB` to do that in the first place when it is part of the operation, semantically.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply functional design principles consequently, you don't ever update state in place. This implies to not have any data structures allowing this (as is the case for your `ClassB` with that setter). You'd rather return a new instance of that class with the updated value(s). And if you do that, there's no need to "abuse" either `map` or `flatMap` but you can make use of a closure instead:

```
return myService.findA()
    .flatMap(a -> myService.findB(a).map(b -> b.copyWith(a)))
    .map(MyType::of)
    .orElse(MyType.empty());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably prefer to go with the first implementation since the major feature that Optional offers in transforming, I would assume it would be best to put that to good use.

Comment: The major feature of `Optional` is providing a means to deal with the *effect of absence* in a declarative and convenient way (eventhough `java.util.Optional` is broken)