# Cannot resolve method 'map' Java 8 Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a set of Objects. I want to filter it based on certain criteria, the ones which meet the criteria, I want to perform some action & then do some more mapping.

```
Set<Tasks> v1;
Map<V, Long> vC = v1.stream()
                .filter(t -> someCondition(t))
                //for these filtered operations perform some action
                .forEach(t -> t.performAction(summation(t))
                .map(t->summation(t))
                .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
```

I get an error at the map Cannot resolve method 'map'. If I remove forEach it works. I know forEach is a terminal operation, but I can't think of alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Today (November 2019) I'm not happy with this answer.

The issue is that the `Stream.peek` method is not being used correctly. In fact, `peek` is to be used only for debugging purposes.

And, as @Holger states in the comments section, the `summation` method is being called twice, which clearly indicates this is not a good answer.

I'm keeping my original answer below as a reminder for myself and others, that sometimes streams are not the best fit.

---

You could use the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) operation to achieve what you want:

```
Map<V, Long> vC = v1.stream()
    .filter(t -> someCondition(t))
    .peek(t -> t.performAction(summation(t))
    .map(t->summation(t))
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
```

Comment: …and [the obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488). Besides that, this code calculates `summation(t)` twice, which a shouting for an alternative solution…