# Java init object and set property using Stream

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to clone a list to a new list and set a property in the new list.
I'm trying to use Java8 Stream as it makes cloning simple.
My code works but it gives this code smell from Sonar:

> Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown (squid:S1488)

Is there a way to do this without using a local variable?
code:

```
List<myObject> clonedList = listToClone.stream()
                                                .map(item ->  {
                                                    cloned = new myObject(item);
                                                    cloned.setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle");
                                                    return cloned;
                                                })
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks

Comment: can you edit your question with complete code and error?

Comment: I am not sure that your problem is on the map method. Can you show the rest of the method. The problem I have with your map method is that the variable is not declared in the map method. I always use the smallest scope possible. But it is not your problem here

Comment: @Sodala On the other hand, if cloned isnt a local variable, this wouldnt compile. Strange.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: This answer refers to filter but is basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793560/9354242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning because you have used a new variable `cloned` unnecessarily instead of directly chaining functions like

```
List<myObject> clonedList = listToClone.stream()
    .map(item -> {return (new myObject(item)).setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle");})
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: or just `.map(item -> new myObject(item).setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle"))` assuming `setLifeCycle` doesnt return `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
List<myObject> clonedList = listToClone.stream()
                                       .map(myObject::new)
                                       .map(o -> {
                                           o.setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle");
                                           return o;
                                       })
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I wouldn't ignore the fact that the function to map should be "stateless function to apply to each element".

Comment: @Aomine Well, it would be cleaner to collect the new objects and then call `forEach` on clonedList  setting the properties we need. The question was whether we *can do this without a local variable*.

Comment: "The question was whether we can do this without a local variable". so wouldn't it be _neater_ to do `listToClone.stream()
                                       .map(myObject::new).peek(o -> o.setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle")).collect(toList())` which "yes" is just as bad as having a statefuly `map` function because `peek` should be used for debugging purposes only. anyway, if you're going to suggest this code then atleast state the probems it could cause. the original code shown by OP will work perfectly both sequentially and in parallel, unlike your solution.

Comment: Dont use peek for such reasons it should be used only for debugging thus java documentation says us : 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: @Aomine Why isn't it safe working in parallel? The mapping for each item of the initial list will be executed sequentially anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MyObject{
         private String someLifeCycle;
         private Item item;
          public MyObject(final String someLifeCycle,final Item item){
            this.someLifeCycle = someLifeCycle;
            this.item = item;
           }
          //getters and setters
        }
```

And your code will be like this :

```
    List<MyObject> clonedList = listToClone.stream()
 .map(item -> new MyObject(item,"someLifeCycle")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would give +1 for the UnaryOperator thing, which I havent seen yet. But then -1 for just dropping a bunch of (not so nicely indented) code. So, zero sum game.

Comment: @GhostCat which doesnt even compile.

Comment: @Aomine what doesnot compile?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura `final someLifeCycle`

Comment: Sorry , thats was typo i was typing fast

Comment: @Aomine There is one more thing , you can use builder from lombok and in that case you dont nee a constructor

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Java Stream's .peek()

```
List<myObject> clonedList = 
listToClone.stream()
.map(myObject::new)
    .peek(x -> x.setLifeCycle("someLifeCycle"))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```