# Java stream unexpected result

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following code:

```
Stream.of("Java", "Stream", "Test")
      .peek(s -> System.out.print(s + " "))
      .allMatch(s -> s.startsWith("J"));
```

Why does it print me Java Stream?

Comment: See also [In Java streams is peek really only for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636377/2711488)

Comment: Contrary to popular way of thinking (and actual implementation) it's better to think of streams as if the last operation was pulling elements rather than the stream was pushing them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`allMatch` is *short-circuiting* operation as most of the streams operations are. since `allMatch` returned early that's why `peek` is only printing the first two elements.

Answer (score 3):

Because `allMatch()` checks if everyone element in the stream is true. And since the second was false, it doesn't have to check further.

So `peek()` won't print the 3rd element.

Comment: Yeap, I understood that it wasn't executed for each element and that was my question - why? So you say that it stopped executing on second element and that's why I see only two values?

Comment: Yes. Because the second element for `allMatch()` was false, the stream terminates.