# How to modify and check if modified in java - 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I am modifying an object using java-8

```
users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0).forEach(u -> u.setProperty("value"))
```

However, I want to understand if any object was modified or not... i.e, I want a boolean return value, while this is void.

Any way to do it?

Comment: what does `setProperty` return? a `boolean`?

Comment: why would an object not be modified after you call `setProperty` on it?

Comment: When exactly do you consider an item modified? When you call the setter, or when the setter sets it to a value it did not have before?

Comment: Yes, setting property is considered modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to `peek()`:

```
AtomicBoolean modified = new AtomicBoolean();
users.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.count > 0)
    .peek(u -> modified.set(true))
    .forEach(u -> u.setProperty("value"))
```

If any elements make it through the filter, `modified.get()` will return `true`.

The use of `AtomicBoolean` (or something similar) is required because references used in lambdas must be *effectively final*.

Comment: If you are going that route (using `peek`), why not `boolean modified = users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0).peek(u -> u.setProperty("value")).count() > 0;`? That doesn’t need an `AtomicBoolean`. On the other hand, if you are using `AtomicBoolean`, you don’t need `peek`: `users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0).forEach(u -> { modified.set(true); u.setProperty("value"); });`

Comment: @holger because adding `peek()` to set a flag leaves OP's existing code unchanged - it's easy to add and remove. It doesn't embed the modification detection in with the main code -  see [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). It's clear what each stream method is doing and why it's being called. `peek()` is the right method to use in this case.

Comment: …except that the operation within `peek` will stop working if you remove the terminal operation, hence, there is no real “separation of concerns”, but a not-so-obvious dependency.

Comment: @holger it’s good that the peek won’t work if you take away the terminal operation, because it’s the terminal operation OP wants to count. There *is* a separation of concerns: with peek, you remove the count without touching or affecting any of the other code. Actually, formatted like I have it you can remove it from the stream by commenting out the peek line - how simple is that?

Answer (score 6):

If I get you correctly, you want to know whether there were any matches while performing the operation. You could simply use two statements.

```
boolean anyMatch = users.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.count > 0);
if(anyMatch) users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0).forEach(u -> u.setProperty("value"));
```

Since `anyMatch` stops at the first matching element, there would be redundant work only if there is a long prefix of non-matching elements before the first match.

If that’s a concern, you could use

```
Spliterator<User> sp = users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0).spliterator();
boolean anyMatch = sp.tryAdvance(u -> u.setProperty("value"));
sp.forEachRemaining(u -> u.setProperty("value"));
```

instead.

Comment: read the question -> hey perfect case for a spliterator -> wrote it -> read your answer :| -> deleted mine -> upvoted yours

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a consuming operation, it can only ever be used with methods that don't actually return anything back; that is, using `forEach` ensures a terminal operation in which you don't get a return value back.

If you want to validate that the property is set the way you want it to be, you'd have to check the elements again.

```
users.stream().filter(u -> u.count > 0)
              .allMatch(u -> u.getProperty().equals("value"));
```

Although this speaks more to paranoia than anything else; unless `setProperty` has some other side effect which isn't exposed *here*, then the setter should *always* set the value.  I'd write the above in a unit test for validation purposes, but not in production code.

Comment: No, actually [you don't have to check again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396988/256196).

Comment: @Bohemian:  At a minimum I would say checking in this fashion would be best left to a unit test anyway, especially given that `peek` is really [only meant for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/1079354).