# Calling method on object in Java 8 stream after collecting

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Suppose I have this bit of code:

```
Map<Consumer, Item> map = myStream.parallel()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(e->e,
                e->e, mergeFunction));
```

What I want to do is call a method on each object of the stream after collecting is done.

For example,

```
item.setDate(item.getOneDate());
```

Before the code done sequentially looped through items, put into a map, and at the very end called a bit of the code like the one above, setting a 'date'.

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   Item blah = iterator.next();
   ....
   // code for putting into map
   ...
   blah.setDate(blah.getOneDate());
}
```

Not sure how to do this with Java 8 streams. `forEach`? `peek`?

Comment: `map()` won't do it for you, before collect ?

Comment: show your non stream attempt to better illustrate your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be [controversial](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/308977/243261), but I would use [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
myStream.parallel()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .peek(item -> item.setDate(item.getOneDate()))
```

IMO, this use case invalidates many of the [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636377/1553851) against using `peek()` for state modification, since it's essentially side-effect free (assuming elements are no longer accessible from the stream source). It definitely complies with the only strict requirement of [non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference).

Answer (score 6):

if this must be done after the `collect` operation, just use `forEach`:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {...});
```

if you're only interested in values:

```
map.values().forEach(item -> {...});
```

or only keys:

```
map.keySet().forEach(item -> {...});
```

Comment: Because the parallelization is there to speed things up, while this works, iterating through the map slows things down for me. Would be ideal if I could do it without having to loop through.

Comment: @SS' can you tell me why you have a merge function for the stream approach but don't have any logic to deal with duplicate keys on the imperative approach.

Comment: He didn't show his insertion code at all on the iterative approach. Either way, that collector looks like pseudocode, considering both key and value mappers are `e->e`.

Comment: @shmosel agreed. I was just curious after I saw your answer. if the merge function is indeed needed this means we cannot simply do `.peek(item -> item.setDate(item.getOneDate()))` as that would even set the date of the objects that the merge function has discarded which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Why would it be a problem?

Comment: @shmosel because we're setting the date of objects that we don't even have in the result set. let's say the actual code was `Map<Consumer, Item> map = myStream.parallel()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(e-> getConsumer(e),
                        e->e, (l,r) -> r));` calling `item.setDate` after the collect operation will yield a different result if were to do `.peek(item -> item.setDate(item.getOneDate()))` before the collect operation given there are actually key collisions.

Comment: I don't see why. Whichever element ends up in the map will only ever have its own date.

Comment: @shmosel there might be a misunderstanding here. can you check this [ideone](https://ideone.com/wST1rO) and see what i mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate. I didn't dispute that there may be less items in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with [Jigar Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260990/jigar-joshi). A `map` operation is cleaner. And if you have no need for an intermediate object, just return the same one:

```
myStream.parallelStream()
        .map(i -> { i.setDate(i.getOneDate()); return i; })
        ...
```

That said, I would avoid mutating objects in the middle of a `Stream`. It's bad practice.