# Testing method with variable made using Stream...peek()

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've set up a Mockito test class to test out a method that generates a variable using Java 8 Streams. Essentially, it is a collection of objects (`currentTr`) that have an `isDeleted` property. This is the line that generates that variable.

```
FPTR = Stream.of(currentTR)
        .peek(CMService::markAsDeleted)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet();
```

When run normally, it runs just fine. Objects in that collection are set as deleted.

The issue is that when I run my test cases, this variable does not contain any objects set for deletion (in other word, it seems either the `peek()` or the method specified (`markAsDeleted`) is never called).

I've thought of using `when().thenCallRealMethod()`, however, given that `markAsDeleted` is a void method, I'm getting an error that won't allow me to do that either. Error being:

`when(cmservice.markAsDeleted(anyObject())).thenCallRealMethod();`

java: 'void' type not allowed here

I've mocked up the CMService in the test field as such:

```
@Mock
CMService cmservice;
```

Is there a way to trigger the method call in `.peek()` so that I get the right variable at all or is it a setup issue?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Do not give 50% code and explain what the other code is supposedly doing. If your assumptions about your code were all correct, there wouldnt be a problem, right. SO: give us something that is complete enough to repro the issue!

Comment: [Why are you using `peek` at all in this fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/1079354)  Using `map` to map across each `CMService` object as deleted, then collecting that result in a set would be ***better*** than using a part of the API which isn't intended to be used by typical consumer applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot use `when()` to set up things is because for that to work the mocked method must return something. However there is also a "reversed" API/syntax to do what you want using for example:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(cmservice).markAsDeleted()
```

See [the documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12). There's more. The most generic is the `doAnswer()` method.