# Java stream how to add value in nested List of List

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `List<List<Object>>` type data. I need to add the same value in the List list.
I tried the following but it doesn't work as its type is `List<Boolean>`.

```
List<List<Object>> data = ...;
data.stream().map(v -> v.add("test")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I get in same type `List<List<Object>>` ?

I have the following data:

```
"data": [
        [
            5,
            "Johnny",
            "Lollobrigida"                
        ],
        [
            6,
            "Bette",
            "Nicholson"               
        ],
        [
            7,
            "Grace",
            "Mostel"                
        ],
        [
            8,
            "Matthew",
            "Johansson"                
        ]
     ]
```

I want to change it to:

```
"data": [
        [
            5,
            "Johnny",
            "Lollobrigida",
            "test"
        ],
        [
            6,
            "Bette",
            "Nicholson",
            "test"               
        ],
        [
            7,
            "Grace",
            "Mostel" ,
            "test"               
        ],
        [
            8,
            "Matthew",
            "Johansson",
            "test"                
        ]
     ]
```

Comment: what's wrong with `list.add`?

Comment: Why no `data.forEach(l -> l.add("test"))`?

Comment: I can't get what you want to do. Ahhh okay, then don't use `map`.

Comment: You are mutating the inside lists, why do you need _anything_ back? Just use `forEach`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose [don’t use `peek`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33635717/2711488) for that; that’s nowhere better than `map`. Neither is meant to be used to manipulate the source of the Stream.

Comment: @Holger Convinced!

Answer (score 5):

@Boris the Spider is right : use forEach :

```
data.forEach(v -> v.add("test"));
```

Comment: I don't get why this has been tackled so complex when the answer was just to use a `forEach`. There is no need in creating a `stream` even here :)

Comment: Right, always something more to remove ^^

Answer (score 2):

`List.add()` returns a `boolean`, but you want your `map()` to return the `List` to which you added the new element.

You need:

```
List<List<Object>> out = 
    data.stream()
        .map(v -> {v.add("test"); return v;})
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that if you don't want to mutate the original inner `List`s, you can create a copy of them:

```
List<List<Object>> out = 
    data.stream()
        .map(v -> {
            List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>(v);
            l.add("test"); 
            return l;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the list from `map` after adding the element. Below solution should work for you:

```
List<List<Object>> dataModified = data.stream().map(v -> {
    v.add("test");
    return v;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```