# How would you use streams or lambda instead of for loop in this example?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I would like to rewrite this function using streams if possible.

```
public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
        Permission perm = Permission.valueOf((String) item);

        try {
            if (event.isAdd()) {
                currentRole.add(perm);
            } else {
                currentRole.remove(perm);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addErrorMessage("", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        builder.append(perm.name()).append(";");
    }

    addMessage("", "Transfered permissions " + builder.toString() + " from/to role :" + currentRole.getName());
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why? This task is not really suitable for streams, having side effects.

Comment: It's an excercise for me given by my employer. I should either use streams or lambda

Comment: Whilst fully agreeing that this method has side effects and therefore not really suited to the use of streams, I would see if me IDE would perhaps offer a refactor of the `for` loop to a `stream.forEach`.  It would meet youre employers criteria I believe and depending on your taste it might be considered more readable.  Though you might also want to extract the logic inside the loop to a private method.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting this to stream-functions would look like this:

```
event.getItems().stream()
    .map(item -> Permission.valueOf((String) item))
    .forEach(perm -> {try-clause})
addMessage(event.getItems().stream()
    .map(item -> Permission.valueOf((String) item).name())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(";", "Transfered permissions ", " from/to role :" + currentRole.getName()));
```

Comment: Note this could not get properly tested without all the other classes.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way doing it without peek or is this the only way?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RealSkeptic, I forgot about that issue. I now corrected it to a better approach. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging

Comment: There is someting missing, after transfered permission there also needs to be included the + builder.toString() + like above inside collectors joining. I fixed it myself thanks for the rest :)

Comment: The collect operation should correctly replace your stringbuilder though, concatenating all names seperated by ;. If I made a mistake please edit the answer so future readers get the correct solution.