# How to save this stream thing into a variable

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, functional-programming, stream

I'm printing this out functionally.

```
listaITSAV.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I want to save the sorting of this list in a variable and then print the variable containing the sorting.

note: ListaITSAV is a LinkedList

```
LinkedList<String> listaITSAV = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `peek()` and read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging) to know more about it.

```
listaITSAV.stream().sorted().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is storing the stream itself in a variable.

```
Stream<String> stream = listaITSAV.stream().sorted();

//...some code...

stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**NOTE:** We cannot perform any further operation on a stream if it has already been operated upon or closed.

For example, attempting to do something like this:

```
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

will result in ***java.lang.IllegalStateException*** 
 with a message, *stream has already been operated upon or closed*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming listalTSAV is already declared, not null, and is populated with all the values you want sorted, you can simply collect the results and reassign back to the variable if it is not final like so:

```
LinkedList<String> listaITSAV = new LinkedList<>();
…
listaITSAV = listaITSAV.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Here is the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) for Collectors#toCollection.