# Call function in Java Optional ifPresent with OrElse

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, functional-interface

Suppose I have an Excel like data row class `DataRow` and I would like to compare two rows and call an function to update one cell in a row if these two rows are different. My set up is currently this, using reflection to get each column's value (field):

```java
try {
    Field[] fields = oldRow.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Arrays.stream(fields)
          .forEach(field -> field.setAccessible(true))
          .filter(field -> !field.get(oldRow).equals(field.get(newRow))
          .findAny()
          .ifPresent(newRow.updateACell())
          .orElse(newRow.udpateACell("new value"))
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

However, this code will give me an error because `ifPresent` does not allow 'void' type here. I understand the function should be invoked upon the value `ifPresent` receives, but is there anyway to achieve what I want to without using if else statements or for loop?

Comment: Are you looking for `ifPresentOrElse(unused -> newRow.updateACell(), () -> newRow.updateACell("new value"))`?

Comment: By the way: `forEach(...).filter(...)` should fail to compile, as `forEach` returns `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The base of the code is not compilable. `Stream#forEach` returns `void`, therefore you cannot perform `Stream#filter` on that. Use either `Stream#peek` (please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635717/in-java-streams-is-peek-really-only-for-debugging)) or `Stream#map`.

   ```java
   Arrays.stream(fields)
         .peek(field -> field.setAccessible(true))
         .filter(field -> !field.get(oldRow).equals(field.get(newRow))
         ...
   ```

   Better use an appropriate method to avoid `Stream#map`/`Stream#peek` as of Java 9 (big thanks to [@Slaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695168/call-function-in-java-optional-ifpresent-with-orelse/72695251#comment128407306_72695251)):

   ```java
   Arrays.stream(fields)
         .filter(field -> field.trySetAccessible() && !rowsAreEqual(field, oldRow, newRow))
         ...
   ```
2. The method `Field#get` throws an exception that must be handled. The Stream API is not suitable for it, but you can create a wrapper to avoid the boilerplate.

   ```java
   private static boolean rowsAreEqual(Field field, Row oldRow, Row newRow) {
       try {
           return field.get(oldRow).equals(field.get(newRow));
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           log.warn("Unexpected error", e);
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   ```java
   Arrays.stream(fields)
       .peek(field -> !field.setAccessible(true))
       .filter(field -> rowsAreEqual(field, oldRow, newRow))
       ...
   ```

   Notice, that the outer try-catch is not needed.
3. The argument of `Optional#isPresent` is a `Consumer<T>` and you put there `void`. Although the `Consumer#accept` has a `void` return type, it must be called first. You need to pass the implementation represented by the `Consumer<T>` and not its result:

   ```java
   Arrays.stream(fields)
         .peek(field -> field.setAccessible(true))
         .filter(field -> rowsAreEqual(field, oldRow, newRow))
         .findAny()
         .ifPresentOrElse(
               field -> newRow.updateACell(),
               () -> newRow.udpateACell("new value"));
   ```

Comment: Using `peek` for this seems wrong to me (though it's probably fine). If using Java 9, I would just change the `filter` call to `filter(field -> field.trySetAccessible() && !rowsAreEqual(field, oldRow, newRow))`. Or better, move the attempt to make the field accessible to the `rowsAreEqual` method.

Comment: @Slaw A good note! I have edited the answer and mentioned you there if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: I have also added a link about the appropriate usage of `peek` for sure.